# How to debug random machine crashes?

Tags: linux-mint, graphics, crash

I am running Linux Mint 18.1 Cinnamon 64-bit on a Razer Blade Stealth mostly successfully. All hardware is working other than the touchscreen which works. But acts funnily.

The problem at hand is as follows. For no constant reason it will just die on me:

[image]

[image]

I will have to be using the machine, but it will never crash with a specific sequence.

```
hutber-blade              
    description: Laptop
    product: Blade Stealth (RZ09-01962W52)
    vendor: Razer
    version: 2.04
    serial: BY1714A29301092
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-3.0 dmi-3.0 vsyscall32
    configuration: boot=normal chassis=laptop family=1A586752 sku=RZ09-01962W52 uuid=6838B4E0-713F-BD11-8274-7A152BAE3400
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: Razer
       vendor: Razer
       physical id: 0
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: Razer
          physical id: 0
          version: 6.00
          date: 01/12/2017
          size: 64KiB
          capacity: 15MiB
          capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: 25
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 16GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: Row of chips Synchronous 1867 MHz (0.5 ns)
             product: MT52L1G32D4PG-107
             vendor: Micron
             physical id: 0
             serial: 00000000
             slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
             size: 8GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1867MHz (0.5ns)
        *-bank:1
             description: Row of chips Synchronous 1867 MHz (0.5 ns)
             product: MT52L1G32D4PG-107
             vendor: Micron
             physical id: 1
             serial: 00000000
             slot: ChannelB-DIMM0
             size: 8GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1867MHz (0.5ns)
     *-cache:0
          description: L1 cache
          physical id: 29
          slot: L1 Cache
          size: 128KiB
          capacity: 128KiB
          capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
          configuration: level=1
     *-cache:1
          description: L2 cache
          physical id: 2a
          slot: L2 Cache
          size: 512KiB
          capacity: 512KiB
          capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
          configuration: level=2
     *-cache:2
          description: L3 cache
          physical id: 2b
          slot: L3 Cache
          size: 4MiB
          capacity: 4MiB
          capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
          configuration: level=3
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7500U CPU @ 2.70GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 2c
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7500U CPU @ 2.70GHz
          slot: U3E1
          size: 3500MHz
          capacity: 4005MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 100MHz
          capabilities: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch epb intel_pt tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp cpufreq
          configuration: cores=2 enabledcores=2 threads=4
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: Intel Corporation
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 02
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
        *-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 02
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
             resources: irq:276 memory:db000000-dbffffff memory:90000000-9fffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
        *-usb
             description: USB controller
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
             version: 21
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi xhci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:122 memory:dc310000-dc31ffff
           *-usbhost:0
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 4.10.0-19-generic xhci-hcd
                physical id: 0
                bus info: usb@1
                logical name: usb1
                version: 4.10
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=12 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb:0
                   description: Mouse
                   product: Razer Mamba Charging dock
                   vendor: Razer
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: usb@1:1
                   version: 2.00
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
              *-usb:1
                   description: Keyboard
                   product: Microsoft
                   vendor: Microsoft
                   physical id: 2
                   bus info: usb@1:2
                   version: 7.97
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
              *-usb:2
                   description: Bluetooth wireless interface
                   vendor: Atheros Communications, Inc.
                   physical id: 6
                   bus info: usb@1:6
                   version: 0.01
                   capabilities: bluetooth usb-2.01
                   configuration: driver=btusb maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
              *-usb:3
                   description: Video
                   product: USB Camera
                   vendor: 11121119-000JJ76Y8
                   physical id: 7
                   bus info: usb@1:7
                   version: 0.02
                   serial: 200901010001
                   capabilities: usb-2.01
                   configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb:4
                   description: Keyboard
                   product: Razer Blade Stealth
                   vendor: Razer
                   physical id: 8
                   bus info: usb@1:8
                   version: 2.00
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=500mA speed=12Mbit/s
              *-usb:5
                   description: Human interface device
                   product: Touchscreen
                   vendor: ELAN
                   physical id: 9
                   bus info: usb@1:9
                   version: 10.12
                   capabilities: usb-2.01
                   configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
           *-usbhost:1
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 4.10.0-19-generic xhci-hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@2
                logical name: usb2
                version: 4.10
                capabilities: usb-3.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=6 speed=5000Mbit/s
        *-generic:0
             description: Signal processing controller
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.2
             version: 21
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi cap_list
             configuration: driver=intel_pch_thermal latency=0
             resources: irq:18 memory:dc32d000-dc32dfff
        *-generic:1
             description: Signal processing controller
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 15
             bus info: pci@0000:00:15.0
             version: 21
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=intel-lpss latency=0
             resources: irq:16 memory:dc32c000-dc32cfff
        *-generic:2
             description: Signal processing controller
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 15.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:15.1
             version: 21
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=intel-lpss latency=0
             resources: irq:17 memory:dc32b000-dc32bfff
        *-communication
             description: Communication controller
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 16
             bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
             version: 21
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=mei_me latency=0
             resources: irq:280 memory:dc32a000-dc32afff
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             version: f1
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:18 memory:dc000000-dc1fffff
           *-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
                vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
                logical name: wlp1s0
                version: 32
                serial: 9c:b6:d0:1a:bf:f7
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=4.10.0-19-generic firmware=WLAN.RM.2.0-00180-QCARMSWPZ-1 ip=192.168.15.220 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
                resources: irq:281 memory:dc000000-dc1fffff
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.4
             version: f1
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:16 ioport:2000(size=4096) memory:c4000000-da0fffff ioport:a0000000(size=570425344)
        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.0
             version: f1
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:16 memory:dc200000-dc2fffff
           *-storage
                description: Non-Volatile memory controller
                product: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd
                vendor: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:3b:00.0
                version: 00
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: storage pm msi pciexpress msix nvm_express bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=nvme latency=0
                resources: irq:16 memory:dc200000-dc203fff
        *-generic:3
             description: Signal processing controller
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1e
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1e.0
             version: 21
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=intel-lpss latency=0
             resources: irq:20 memory:dc329000-dc329fff
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 21
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master
             configuration: latency=0
        *-memory
             description: Memory controller
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
             version: 21
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz (30.3ns)
             configuration: driver=intel_pmc_core latency=0
             resources: irq:0 memory:dc324000-dc327fff
        *-multimedia
             description: Audio device
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
             version: 21
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=32
             resources: irq:282 memory:dc320000-dc323fff memory:dc300000-dc30ffff
        *-serial UNCLAIMED
             description: SMBus
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.4
             version: 21
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:dc328000-dc3280ff ioport:f040(size=32)
  *-power UNCLAIMED
       physical id: 1
```

Comment: Does it only happen when you have an external monitor connected? Anything interesting in `~/.xsession-errrors` or `/var/log/xorg.0/log`? Can you fix this by running `cinnamon --replace &` or by running the right `xrandr` command to reset your screen layout? Perhaps disabling one screen using xrand and then re-enabling it?

Comment: 95% it is a video driver problem. I would give a 500% punishment tax for the hardware vendors not giving the source code or at least a complete documentation of their hardware.

Comment: Does it become completely unresponsive (to the network, to Alt+SysRq, …), or is the problem only with the display? The first thing to do is a memory test (pick that at the boot prompt, let it run overnight).

Comment: I left the machine at work. But on Tuesday I will give your suggestions a try when it happens again... because it will happen again ;)

Comment: I am back at work today and it has crashed twice in the last 40mins now. I cannot use shortscuts using the `SysRq` as the stealth keyboard nor the comfort curve I am using seem to have this key. Both do have the print screen key however. I have tried the `cntrl+alt+2` which does nothing. I think its just a complete failure. I need to check the logs now to see if anything in there makes sense. I have reset the `Xorg` log so I know where to look for the errors now.

Comment: @Gilles I now have a keyboard and am back on this machine... its crashed 6 times already today :( The machine is completely unresponsive during this time. The bounty message was meant to read `Now` lol

Comment: Have you tried to switch from Cinnamon to Mate (see how here https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-hardware-18/linux-mint-cinnamon-17-3-in-software-rendering-mode-issue-4175571760/)? I experienced display issues with Intel graphics card (my screen looked like yours while any animation was being processed by the system, but it was not crashing) when using Cinnamon, gone after I switched to Mate.

Comment: Have you tested your RAM? Also, check that all your fans are working and clean. A bad RAM chip or excessive heat can cause random crashes.

Comment: I will need to test my ram then, I have realised it only ever crashes exactly as I do some action. So this won't happen if I just left the machine over night. I am now using mate and the crashes are indeed less frequent, they are definitely still happening.

Comment: I've tested the ram now... everything seemed to be ok. So its a graphical error on the software side or its a hardware fault that is causing the software to crash I believe

Comment: I can confirm its not heat either, as it happened this morning and it was "cold" so not heat.

Answer (score 0):

Is your graphics unit in the laptop overheating? I had that same distorted screen when the video GPU in my laptop overheated.

Also, one time I subbed in an extra 4 GB memory module and it was at a different speed (same DDR format tho) and it sometimes did that.

I'd start by disabling discreet graphics for a enough time to test it and see if it isn't hardware caused.

Comment: Thanks Saint. I will get on google to see how to disable discreet graphics!

Comment: Is there any point in disabling discreet graphics when its an intel card?

Comment: It is prob a setting in the BIOS. Just try it and see if it helps. Mine (thinkpad) when it got hot and the discreet graphics was on ... bzzzt that is when it does it. Otherwise maybe some testing software can diagnose.